# Bevel modifier causes incorrect normals

Tags: modifiers, shaders, bevel

I'm trying to apply the modifier to the closet and the window you see in the screenshot (I'm actually following a tutorial so he might have different settings, but I didn't manage to solve my issue). The modifier works just fine on the bed frame though.

What is also strange is that if I try to change any settings, or even apply them without copying from the bed frame, they don't get applied to the window or the closet. The *Auto Smooth* is set to $180°$, and if I try to change it I see the difference only if I go below a specific range, like it's the same between $90°$ and $°180$, and only below $90°$ it changes.

I already tried applying the scale, and re-make them again, but nothing worked. At this point, I have no idea about what I should do.

[image: screenshot of blender interface]

This is how it should look:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Of course the _Auto Smooth_ doesn't show any changes between 90° and 180°. The value means, every angle below this gets shaded smooth. Since you seem to have mostly 90° angles on your objects, there is nothing above 90° which is not smoothed. Setting _Auto Smooth_ to 180° is like disabling it completely.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann the thing is that I also tried to follow what the guy in the tutorial had, and he applied 180° to all of the above-mentioned objects. And with 90° they don't change much in terms of being close at least to the result I'm trying to achieve. Thank you for the hint tho!

Comment: The _Auto Smooth_ option is used to have smooth objects not overly smoothed so that certain angles still look sharp. It only really makes sense to use it with values below 90°, that's why the default value is 30°. What tutorial is that, because setting it to 180° makes absolutely no sense - but I wouldn't say that every tutor always knows what he's doing...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3hI38dAaI0&t=737s&ab_channel=LeftBrainCGArt If you go to minute 24:29 you can see when he sets the auto-smooth to 180. 

I'm a total noob in Blender, and I'm trying to learn my way around the software, I tried to figure this thing out, but I'm just stuck in here with this weird looking objects 

Comment: @AlexKrugeri I guess you have messed up your mesh somehow. Go to _Object Data Properties_ and under _Geometry Data_ check if there is a button _Clear Custom Split Normals Data_. If so, click on it so that it resets to _Add Custom Split Normals Data_. The reason why he sets _Auto Smooth_ to 180° is that he does not actually want the _Auto Smooth_ to take care of sharpening the edges, but he enables the _Harden Normals_ option in the _Bevel_ modifier, and this needs _Auto Smooth_ to be enabled in order to work. But without the modifier this setting would be useless.

Comment: He probably has enabled the Shading > Harden Normals option of the Bevel modifier, which needs the Auto Smooth enabled and will smooth the bevels but not the faces, have you enabled this option? Edit: Oops but yours seems to be enabled

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann the button is not active

Comment: As Gordon says you need to Clear Custom Split Normals Data, also merge by distance the whole mesh because you have overlapping vertices, and set the Bevel Amount value to 0.02

Comment: *"Setting Auto Smooth to 180° is like disabling it completely."* - with some exceptions, as you figured out, whenever custom split normals are used, they require autosmooth, but also if you mark edges sharp and want that to be used in shading, you too need auto smooth.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Well, the _Harden Normals_ part I mentioned... and for split normals this is true, too. But if I for example simply mark certain edges as sharp and set _Auto Smooth_ to 180° (or anything from 90° to above), those edges will be smoothed although marked sharp - so it is the same as disabling it completely, or at least it looks the same enabled and disabled.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Have you actually tried it? Because I did, and I do see the sharp edges where I marked them.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes, I have... this is what it looks like when using only _Mark Sharp_ in _Edit Mode_ [sharp edges](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S0-QW3HB3FFTxrVGjx0c4NulXwrL8_Jd/view?usp=sharing) - it's in almost all cases no difference. And this is when I select all and create custom split normals [custom split normals](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dGogZP5C6HXlOJGxEewTzpooZgd1nA3p/view?usp=sharing). If I don't require specific edges to be sharp while all others are smooth, I usually get away with only using _Auto Smooth_ set to a reasonable angle below 90°.

Comment: From the screen shot alone you can see that the normals of the mesh are messed up. A simple recalculation usually fixes this. If they were correctly aligned, you wouldn't see these light and dark splotches in places, where it should be shaded uniformly. With messed up normals the bevel modifier can not compute in which direction it should bevel the edges.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann my point was exactly that: https://i.imgur.com/O8pjQnp.png autosmooth with 180° makes sense if you want to manually mark sharp edges, but avoid any sharpness on edges not marked sharp.

Comment: Hi, people.. this discussion has got a little too long for the comments section, so I've moved it to chat. When settled, i'll clean up some of the commentary from here.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146035/discussion-on-question-by-alex-krugeri-bevel-modifier-issue); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Gordon says, you need to reset the normals, in the *Object Data panel > Geometry Data*, click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*. Also you have overlapping vertices, which prevents the bevel (because it will make some faces intersect), you need to select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.

Comment: Thank you so much for adding your solution as a formal answer! I really appreciate your help in resolving my issue. Your solution worked perfectly and solved the problem. I've upvoted your answer and marked the question as answered. Thanks!

Comment: You're wekcome  ;)

Comment: I'm so stupid... just reading your first sentence (which was just a guess on my behalf and not the problem in this case) and then writing my own answer about merging :D

Answer (score 4):

I cannot recap what exactly you did with your mesh. But the only thing I saw immediately is that the *Auto Merge* option at the top of the viewport is not enabled - which he uses in the tutorial and explains that this might help merging vertices that are accidentally duplicated.

So I ignored the strange shading and when I looked at your mesh I saw that despite the fact you have set the bevel *Amount* to 0.04 m, there is absolutely no bevel visible on the edges - which means the *Clamp Overlap* option is limiting the bevel because there are vertices too close together, like: in the same location.

Pressing <kbd>A</kbd> in *Edit Mode* on the cupboard to select all and then <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance* resulted in the message: "Removed 40 vertice(s)". After that, the edges were beveled and the shading looked normal. On the window there were 24 vertices removed.

I can only recommend to every beginner to thoroughly and carefully follow a tutorial to make sure you are doing everything like it is shown there to eliminate possible errors.